# Write String to permanent flash memory of Arduino ESP32

Tags: arduino, esp32, flash-memory, eeprom

I want to write some text into the flash memory of an Arduino ESP32. It works kinda but not as I want it to.

```
void writeString(const char* toStore, int startAddr) {
  int i = 0;
  for (; i < LENGTH(toStore); i++) {
    EEPROM.write(startAddr + i, toStore[i]);
  }
  EEPROM.write(startAddr + i, '\0');
  EEPROM.commit();
}
```

My call

```
writeString("TEST_STRING_TO_WRITE", 0);
```

only writes TEST into the memory. I do not understand why. Is that because of the _? Or am I missing something different?

Here is the used LENGTH macro

```
#define LENGTH(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]))
```

and the method I use to read the string from the memory again (which seems to work correctly):

```
String readStringFromFlash(int startAddr) {
  char in[128];
  char curIn;
  int i = 0;
  curIn = EEPROM.read(startAddr);
  for (; i < 128; i++) {
    curIn = EEPROM.read(startAddr + i);
    in[i] = curIn;
  }
  return String(in);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where on earth did you get that `LENGTH` macro from? It’s surreal.

`sizeof` will not do what you want here. It’s a compile-time function that computes the storage requirements of its argument. In this case it should return the length in bytes of a character pointer, not the string it points to.

You want to use strlen(), assuming your char* is a properly terminated C string. Add one to make sure the ‘\0’ at the end gets stored, too.

```
#define LENGTH(x) (strlen(x) + 1)
```

Comment: it's from visual studio. thanks a lot, its working now. But I thought sizeof(x) gives the size of the array in bytes. And that has to be devided by the size of the datatype in the array to get the number of elements

Comment: If you had `char string[23];` then `sizeof(string);` would return 23, even if you only stored a 5 character string in the character array. If you then passed `string` as an argument to a function and used `sizeof` inside the function, you'd (most likely, it would depend on the CPU) get 4 because the function would only know about a `char *`.  `sizeof` returns the number of bytes needed to store whatever its argument is.

Comment: This gets really bad with `String` - if you did `sizeof(String("verylongstring"))`, you'll get the number of bytes needed to store a `String` object, not the number of bytes it allocated to store its data. This bites people all the time.

Answer (score 3):

Below is the code to demonstrate the storing as well as retrieving of the string `ssid` in the EEPROM (permanent storage).

```c
#include "EEPROM.h"

int addr = 0;
#define EEPROM_SIZE 64

// the sample text which we are storing in EEPROM
char ssid[64] = "CARNIVAL OF RUST";

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println("starting now...");

    if (!EEPROM.begin(EEPROM_SIZE)) {
        Serial.println("failed to init EEPROM");
        while(1);
    }

    // writing byte-by-byte to EEPROM
    for (int i = 0; i < EEPROM_SIZE; i++) {
        EEPROM.write(addr, ssid[i]);
        addr += 1;
    }
    EEPROM.commit();

    // reading byte-by-byte from EEPROM
    for (int i = 0; i < EEPROM_SIZE; i++) {
        byte readValue = EEPROM.read(i);

        if (readValue == 0) {
            break;
        }

        char readValueChar = char(readValue);
        Serial.print(readValueChar);
    }
}

void loop() {

}
```